# Intercept and block connection whit Java like a firewall

Tags: java, connection, block, firewall, intercept

I have an question:

How i can intercept the connection (For example from IP Adress: 100.100.100.101) and block it, like a firewall?

I dont have any idea where to start.

I think about ServerSocket but just work in a current socket.

Thanks for read the question.
Have a good night.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `ServerSocket` and listen for connections. When a connection is made you can check the IP against a rule set and either close the connection immediately or allow the session to continue.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
Socket s = ss.accept();
if(isAllowed(s.getInetAddress()){
    //Do something useful.
} else {
    // Not allowed, close socket.
    s.close();
}
```

EDIT: 
As commented this doesn't actually allow you to block the connection, but it is the best that can be done with Java.

Comment: @EJP If you want a firewall you need to use a firewall you won't be able to prevent the actual connection using Java. This is at least something useful that can be done from Java.

Comment: I agree but it doesn't answer his question, and it doesn't contain the information that this is the best that can be done.

Comment: Yes, but i need to block the IP from all sockets for example port 80.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write a firewall in Java.

Comment: @user1233315 Because Java doesn't provide the necessary support. You need not only raw sockets, which Java doesn't have, but the ability to suppress a packet altogether, which means interposing something in the OS TCP stack.